# S3 - TransferManager get num uploads in progress, complete and failed

Tags: java, file-upload, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm using the Java AWS SDK to build an application that among other things has to upload some files to S3.

Provided I have access to a TransferManager object tx ( in Java ) is there any way to get info. regarding the uploads that are associated with this object ? I want to know how many of the associated uploads are complete, in progress, failed.

Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this other than to keep track of the `Upload` objects yourself.  Each call to one of `TransferManager`'s `upload(...)` methods will return such an object, and you can ask it for its status, wait for it to complete, etc.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Upload.html

Comment: Is it possible to get the `File` related to the current `Upload` object? say for removing this file from the local storage when the upload to s3 is successful.